# Uso de palavra reservada "import" em javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Lendo o código do Ghost, plataforma CMS baseada em NodeJS encontrei um arquivo com a seguinte declaração:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import 'ghost/utils/link-component';
import 'ghost/utils/text-field';
import config from './config/environment';
```

Pesquisando na internet já encontrei algo sobre ser ES6. Mas é uma aplicação que está sendo usada em produção, ambiente não muito favorável a experimentos como a ES6. Agora vem as dúvidas

Eles usam alguma biblioteca externa ou é por conta de alguma feature já ativa que possibilita o uso da ES6?

PS: O ghost usa Ember com já podemos ver nesse import e o arquivo caso queiram consultar é esse aqui, [código para Ghost no Github](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/app/app.js)

Comment: O Ghost suporta Node 0.12 e IO.js que já são (quase 100%) ES6. Mas possivelmente estão a usar um _ES6-transpiler_ (conversor de ES6 para ES5)

Answer (score 1):

ES6 não é mais experimental, foi renomeada para ES2015, e já foi aprovada desde Junho.

A maioria dos browsers já estão implementando a grande maioria das suas especificações, e já existem transpilers muito confiáveis para que você já possa utilizar a grande maioria de suas features, que serão compiladas e traduzidas em Javascript (ES5).

Os maiores transpilers que existem hoje em dia são o Babel (antigamente chamado de 6to5) e o traceur (by Google). Eu prefiro o Babel, visto que já possui 73% das features "transpiláveis".

Você pode ver o compat-table do ES6: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Existem alguns frameworks Javascript, como o [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) que já foram feitos 100% desenvolvidos em ES6 (e algumas coisas de ES7 até, como os decorators e a declaração de propriedades fora do construtor).

---

O ES6 é interessantíssimo, e provavelmente teremos todas as features implementadas nos Evergreen Browsers até o final deste ano/começo do ano que vem - portanto, sugiro que comece a estudá-lo desde já.

Quanto ao "import", é algo que já vem sendo utilizado há um bom tempo no ES5 através de libraries como o Require, e hoje em dia a library que segue bem as especificações do ES6 é o System.JS

Comment: Eu já tenho estudado o ES6, mas foi mais pelo curiosidade de saber que o Ghost usando e resposta sobre Node 0.12, foi bem objetiva.